# Better Way to Handle Nested Monad?

Tags: scala

Given a list of names:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> val names: Future[List[String]] = 
            Future.successful( List("Joe Foo", "Jane Bar") )
names: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = 
           scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@3dddbe65
```

And, a method that, for a given `name`, returns a `Future[String]` for that name's hobby:

```
scala> def getHobby(name: String): Future[String] = Future.successful( "poker" )
getHobby: (name: String)scala.concurrent.Future[String]
```

With `names`, i.e. `Future[List[String]]`, I can get those names' hobby via:

```
scala> names.map(_.map(getHobby))
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[List[scala.concurrent.Future[String]]] =
         scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@42c28305
```

But, then I have a somewhat hard-to-read, nested monad, `Future[List[Future[String]]`.

I can clean it up:

```
scala> res3.map(Future.sequence(_))
res5: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]]] = 
      scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@4eaa375c

scala> res5.flatMap(identity)
res6: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = 
   scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@101bdd1c
```

And then gets it value.

```
scala> res6.value
res7: Option[scala.util.Try[List[String]]] = Some(Success(List(poker, poker)))
```

But, is there a cleaner, more idiomatic way to perform the above work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to flatten the data as it's retrieved.

```
scala> names.flatMap(x => Future.sequence(x.map(getHobby)))
res54: scala.concurrent.Future[List[String]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@45cd45aa
```

Comment: Similarly you can use `Future.traverse` this way: `names.flatMap(x => Future.traverse(x)(name => getHobby(name)))`

Answer (score 2):

Just for illustration (of nested monad), you also have "[Scalaz Monad Transformers](http://Scalaz%20Monad%20Transformers)", described by [Rama Nallamilli](https://twitter.com/rama_nallamilli).

> Take `Future` for example, all these cases below are monads nested within a monad.

```
Future[Option[T]]
Future[List[T]]
Future[scalaz.\/[A, B]]
```

In the case of a nested monad such as `Future[List[Int]]`, Rama suggests:

> When choosing which monad transformer to use, you always choose the inner most type, in this case List[Int] is our inner most type so we will use the (Scalaz) `ListT` monad transformer.
>
> The ListT apply function is as follows:

```
def apply[A](a: M[List[A]]) = new ListT[M, A](a)
```

> Therefore we can use this to convert our `Future[List[Int]]` to the `ListT` monad type which in this case will be a `ListT[Future, Int]`.
>   We can now write our addition in terms of the new monad type which has abstracted the mapping of the `Future`:

```
@ for {
    i <- ListT(x)
    j <- ListT(y)
  } yield i + j 
res20: ListT[Future, Int] = ListT(Success(List(5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9)))
```

In summary:

> monad transformers give you a powerful abstraction to work on the underlying data of a monadic type when it itself is wrapped in a monad.
>   It reduces code complexity and enhances readability by abstracting the wiring of drilling down into the nested datatypes.
>
> ScalaZ provides implementations of monad transformers for many types including EitherT, [`ListT`](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/ListT.scala), [`OptionT`](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/OptionT.scala) and [`ReaderT`](http://scalaz.github.io/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/ReaderT.scala) to name a few.